# How to navigate Login page to split view controller in iOS

Tags: ios7

I am newbie to iOS application development.  I have problem to navigate Login page to split view controller (Master and Detail view controller).

Currently i created login form.  After getting authentication, user can navigate to split view controller.

Here is login submit method code

```
  DetailViewManager *detailViewManager = (DetailViewManager*)self.splitViewController.delegate;
  UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;
  FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
  detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
  detailViewManager.detailViewController = detailViewController;
  [newDetailViewController release];
```

There is no response this code. ( No error occurred).

Any idea or link to navigate Normal login page to split view controller page using code.  ( I am not using storey board) should be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.